# How to make recharts custom tooltip to be clickable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

As i was trying to add link in my custom tooltip of recharts, i can not able to hover on tooltip content it will be hidden automatically, is there any props that i need to override for  of recharts to make it clickable?.

Below is my tooltip

```
  <Tooltip content={(value)=>renderTooltip(value)} />
```

Below is my renderTooltip which i am using it

```
const renderTooltip = (props) => {
   if (props.active) {
     return (
       <div >
         <div className="tool-tip">

           <span className="tool-tip-footer">
             {' '}
            <a href="SOME_VALUE_FROM_PROPS">Google</a>
          </span>

      </div>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: For latest version  of recharts they have added new prop called trigger, when we pass trigger as click then it will be clickable, by default it will be hover.

Comment: where is the prop `trigger` in the docs; I was referring to this page https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Tooltip

Comment: @user19251203 they havent updated docs yet.

Answer (score 2):

I got this working by doing adding `trigger='click'` prop and adding a style `pointer-events: auto` to the parts of the tooltip I wanted to be clickable.

The recharts tooltip wrapper has `pointer-events: none` which prevented clicking it even after changing the `trigger`.

Comment: yes even i got it by setting poiner-events: auto

Answer (score 0):

The `Tooltip` component calculates internally if the content has to be shown or not, so you don't have to. This might be causing some issues beyond your control.

Comment: you should have ask this in a comment instead of posting a new answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33242337)